# Write on pictures

Tags: graphics

Is there a way to write on pictures using LaTeX, and I don't mean like including graphics and all, I mean like writing on pictures directly. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use TikZ as described in the answers to this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9559/45161

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major problem is find the correct coordinates inside the image. For this purpose you could use [TikzEdt](http://www.tikzedt.org/).
For example if the image is (myLogo.png):

[image: my logo]

You can import it inside a tikzpicture in TikzEdt as show in the code in this image:

[image: tikzedt window]

Now you can know the coordinates of points inside the image. They are in the right bottom corner.
For example using the previous image, you can easily do this:

[image: Example of use of Tikzedt]

The previous figure was generate using TikzEdt for find the correct coordinates and draw the other elements (red arrow and rectangle) and then the resulting tikzpicture is being put inside a standalone document. The code is the following:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
lSt/.style={red,line width=7pt},
wrSt/.style={font=\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{ptm}\fontsize{45}{45}\bfseries}]
\node{\includegraphics{TikzEdtWindowCapture}};
\draw[lSt]  (14,-8.5) rectangle (15.7,-9.7)coordinate (v1);
\draw[lSt] (v1) -- +(-45:1cm) node[below,wrSt]{coordinate of the figure};
\draw[<-,>=stealth,lSt] (9.3,2.4) .. controls (14.5,2.1) and (19.5,2.5) .. (19.4,6.1)node[above,wrSt]{my logo};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```