# What's the best way to write over an image?

Tags: graphics, pstricks, shell-escape, pdftricks

I'm trying to write text over an image like this exemple:
[image]

I've read  a lot about this topic but as I'm quite a beginner with Latex I'm lost (I'm using Overleaf with pdflatex btw).

I did the exemple with this code:

```
preambule.tex
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage[miktex]{pdftricks} 
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

main.tex
\input{preambule}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(2.6,0)(21,3)
  \uput[ur](0,0){\includegraphics[width=20.6cm,height=3cm]{images/Bandeau.jpg}}
  \uput[u](10,2){\textbf{\LARGE{Rapport 1 mois de stage}}}
  \uput[u](10,1){\textbf{\large{JLR}}}
  \uput[u](10,0.5){\textbf{4A GBM}}
  \uput[u](10,0){\textbf{Octobre 2020}}
\end{pspicture}

\section{Environnement}
```

But I still have some warnings that I don't really understand:

Package pdftricks Warning: **************************************** No \write 18 capability. You'll have to run a script by yourself! ****************************************.

Package pdftricks Warning: **************************************** Package pdftricks v,1.16 loaded [psTricks support in PDF (CVR, ACL)] ****************************************.

So, I would like to know if it is a good solution and how I can remove those warnings. Or do I have to use tikz (such as [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/260949/229623)) even if I find it more difficult than pstricks ? What's the real difference(s) between this two solutions?

I've also read about
`pdftex--shell-escape` or `\write18`  but I don't know where to introduce it in my document because I do not use commands.

Well, if someone can clarify those points...
Thanks!

Comment: which engine to you want to use? pdflatex?

Comment: My previous answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/569888/162128)

Answer (score 5):

There is no need for pstricks or complicated stuff. You can simple go back and write over a picture:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}\raisebox{3cm}{\hspace{-4cm}\Huge Some Text}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Run with `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx,mwe}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\newsavebox\IBox
\sbox\IBox{\includegraphics{example-grid-100x100pt.png}}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(\wd\IBox,\ht\IBox)
\rput[lb](0,0){\usebox\IBox}%
\psline[linecolor=white,linewidth=5pt](\wd\IBox,\ht\IBox)%
\psline[linecolor=white,linewidth=5pt](0,\ht\IBox)(\wd\IBox,0)
\psline[linecolor=white,linewidth=2pt](0,0.5\ht\IBox)(\wd\IBox,0.5\ht\IBox)
\psline[linecolor=white,linewidth=2pt](0.5\wd\IBox,\ht\IBox)(0.5\wd\IBox,0)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]